# How can I import data into mysql database via mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a database in mysql. I have a .sql file. how can i import it into my database via mysql workbench ?

Comment: Click on central login which has `Import/Export` labelled below it...

Comment: mysqlworkbench5.5 There's a separate option for import/export in Server Administration. Import doesn't allow the schema to be chosen

Answer (score 85, accepted):

- Under **Server Administration** on the Home window select the server instance you want to restore database to (Create **New Server Instance** if doing it first time).
- Click on **Manage Import/Export**
- Click on **Data Import/Restore** on the left side of the screen.
- Select **Import from Self-Contained File** radio button (right side of screen)
- Select the path of .sql
- Click **Start Import** button at the right bottom corner of window.

Hope it helps.

---Edited answer---

Regarding selection of the schema. MySQL Workbench (5.2.47 CE Rev1039) does not yet support exporting to the user defined schema. It will create only the schema for which you exported the .sql... In 5.2.47 we see "New" target schema. But it does not work. I use MySQL Administrator (the old pre-Oracle MySQL Admin beauty) for my work for backup/restore.
You can still download it from Googled trustable sources (search MySQL Administrator 1.2.17).

Comment: Thanks I'm doing the same but it says no schema selected. I'm given an option to select schema while exporting but now while importing

Comment: How to select the schema while importing

Comment: Thanks so what's to be done next? Do you know a way via mysql client ?

Comment: As I mentioned I used "MySQL Administrator 1.2.17"... Oracle discontinued this Awesome product and replaced it with MySQL Workbench. You can either download MySQL Admin (from some old sources) or use mysqldump command line utility.

Comment: There are some sources who still offer it for download. Google for it - MySQL Administrator 1.2.17

Comment: and what if the file is not `.sql` but `.dump` ? Workbench doesn't let you open it.

Comment: I got a folder which contains many .sql files. My teammates imported them through Workbench's Server tab. In my MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 there isn't such tab. How can I import all those files? I am using Linux Mint 16.

Comment: I've used this feature on version 8 and it works just fine.

Comment: In the data import menu, you have to select "Default Target Schema" and choose one of them (usually you create a new one before the import). If the former option is disabled, check "Import from Self-Contained" file first. That will enable it. This solved the error for me (ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 14: No database selected).

Answer (score 9):

For MySQL Workbench 6.1:
in the home window click on the server instance(connection)/ or create a new one.
In the thus opened 'connection' tab click on 'server' -> 'data import'.
The rest of the steps remain as in Vishy's answer.

Answer (score 8):

1. Open Connetion
2. Select "Administration" tab
3. Click on Data import

Upload sql file

[image]

Make sure to select your database in this award winning GUI:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for my past me. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For *MySQL Workbench 8.0* navigate to:

```
Server > Data Import
```

A new tab called **Administration - Data Import/Restore** appears. There you can choose to import a Dump Project Folder or use a specific SQL file according to your needs.
Then you must select a schema where the data will be imported to, or you have to click the <kbd>New...</kbd> button to type a name for the new schema.

Then you can select the database objects to be imported or just click the <kbd>Start Import</kbd> button in the lower right part of the tab area.

Having done that and if the import was successful, you'll need to update the *Schema Navigator* by clicking the arrow circle icon.

That's it!

For more detailed info, check the [MySQL Workbench Manual: 6.5.2 SQL Data Export and Import Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html)