# MySQL Workbench generate diagrams out of data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagram

I have connection to my database in MySQL Workbench and I would like to create erd diagram or if it is possible others diagrams. I have been using Ubuntu 14.04. I tried reading articles and manuals on the official website. They were unhelpful. Can you give me any instruction or advice how not to create my database by hand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the Reverse Engineering Wizard against your database. For additional information, see:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-live.html

This creates an EER diagram and model from your database.

Comment: Thank you, it works super. But database looks like a set of table, maybe you know how to do it like a complex schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your database for an file. For example in MySQLAdmin
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html

And then you can import this in your Workbench

1. Under Server Administration on the Home window select the server
   instance you want to restore database to (Create New Server Instance
   if doing it first time).
2. Click on Manage Import/Export
3. Click on Data Import/Restore on the left side of the screen.
4. Select Import from Self-Contained File radio button (right side of
   screen)
5. Select the path of .sql
6. Click Start Import button at the right bottom corner of window.

[How can I import data into mysql database via mysql workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884693/how-can-i-import-data-into-mysql-database-via-mysql-workbench)

This will build your database model

Comment: It wasn't an answer for my question in real, but it is helpful for the import/export task. Thank you.