# Working with .sql file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having an old project which have server language is php. The project have .sql file database. How can we deal with this .sql file (i.e open in database program like MySQL workbench) to see the list of table and the corresponding data type, and real data type store in that table?

Any help is much appreciate.

P.S.: My php folder is zip and download from production server. I need to find out the incorrect data in .sql table (i.e see table content, real data inside)

Comment: Are you struggling to open sql file or you want to perform any operation on it? Can you please explain bit more about your problem

Comment: Hi I have edited question. Basically i need to find out what is the database content and real data inside

Comment: `SQL` is just `language`, not a data. Just open it in your text editor, or import to some database (`mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`).

Comment: I am not sure. It .sql

Answer (score 0):

.sql file is actually a database dump. You will have to import it using any MySQL management tool like phpmyadmin or MySQL workbench. See this thread

[How can I import data into mysql database via mysql workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884693/how-can-i-import-data-into-mysql-database-via-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Thanks for your help. What is the recommended way. PhpMyAdmin or MySQL workbench?

Comment: For most of the web servers phpmyadmin is default tool. So I recommend to use phpmyadmin.

Comment: My situation is that i don't have access to production server. I only have zip folder php contain .sql file. Need to troubleshooting this database and find out the incorrect data (double number but store as string, need to find incorrectly input

Comment: If you have some script which is using this database then you will need to install web server with mysql server on your local machine. What Operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm Using a Mac now . I have install PhP storm and MySQL workbench. If needed will install PhpMyAdmin also

Comment: You do not need to install phpmyadmin. You can work with MySQL workbench and import sql file in your database. You may need to create a new database first. I sent you a link in the answer.

Comment: PhpStorm can to operate with databases. Nothing else required.

Comment: Sorry i'm still struggling can find any option how to create new database in MySQL work bench 6. phpStorm can read but there is no table structure for easy reading (row, column...)

Comment: You can find complete tutorial here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html